# How does Windows OS keep track of a processes virtual memory?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual-memory

**Background:**
So I know in modern operating systems a process basically has a full 32-bit (or 64-bit) address space to work with. As far as I know the actual virtual memory addresses for the process are first stored within the program's .exe file. Meaning the linker will patch up all function references and variables with actual addresses such as 0x00007fb6. To my understanding, these virtual addresses (or some modified version of them due to the loader) can eventually be mapped to actual physical addresses in RAM.

**Issue:**
My question is when authors talk about things like mapping something into a program's virtual address space, e.g. mapping file contents, what exactly do they mean? As far as I can conceptualize the OS gets an individual process's virtual address from the .exe so if another file's contents was being mapped into that process's virtual address space then would those contents be saved back to the exe file? Or does the OS just keep track of the added contents behind the scenes some how?

Comment: An "exe file" is treated as read-only. After initial load, the process metadata is all stored in the kernel's memory (and thrown away on process exit). Go grab a Windows Internals book if you want the gory details.

Comment: Alternatively, you can look at the [Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html) - the Windows kernel is fairly similar (inner structures and layout differ, but general methods are the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, if you want a deep dive into this kind of thing, I'd heavily suggest grabbing a copy of [Windows Internals, Part 1: System architecture, processes, threads, memory management, and more, 7th Edition](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-internals-part-1-system-architecture-processes-9780735684188). It does a good job of explaining the details. Alternatively, look at e.g. [Linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand007.html), which is more publicly available - it's going to be a bit different but follows many of the same concepts as Windows.

[Here](https://manybutfinite.com/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/) is another perhaps more accessible explanation.

You might also want to look at how [page tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) work, and perhaps also [TLBs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer).

---

The gist of it is that when a process attempts a read or write to a specific *page* of its virtual address space, the CPU's memory management unit (MMU)  either translates it to a physical address (by looking at the page tables via the TLB, a special on-chip cache that's just for page table entries) or, if the page table entry says "page not present",  notifies the operating system. That's what's called a *page fault*. In response the OS a) if necessary, assigns a new physical page to the process and loads its contents from "backing store" (pagefile or a mapped file) into that page of RAM, b) updates the page table entry to reflect the physical address of the page, and c) tells the CPU to try again ("dismisses the page fault").

There is a page table entry for each page of defined virtual address space. The page table entries are not only used by the CPU to perform address translation. PTEs corresponding to "not valid" pages - those that would incur a page fault when accessed - are used by the OS to store information about the location of the page's data. Thus PTEs exist for all defined virtual addresses. A subset are normally "valid", ie they correspond to virtual addresses that can be accessed without a page fault. (This subset is called the "working set" of the process.)

The PTEs for "invalid" pages contain information that will let the OS find the page's contents if a fault occurs to that page. The contents may be in a page file, in a mapped file, in RAM (in one of the page caches), in another process's working set (for shared pages), or sometimes nowhere at all (for pages that have been no initial content defined and have not yet been referenced; such pages are simply allocated physically and filled with zeroes on first reference; these events are called "demand-zero page faults").

Page tables are too big to entirely fit in the (very very small) TLB, which is why they are just stored in normal memory.

Page tables are in fact too large to all fit in RAM at once, so they are organized in a tree structure per process, and all except the top-level table of each tree are themselves pageable.

On your typical modern OS, each process will have its own separate page table, keeping process' address space independent of each other. The kernel keeps track of processes and their address spaces within its own memory regions. On current Windows, this is stored along with other process metadata in memory in an "`EPROCESS`" data structure and related structures called Virtual Address Descriptors. Windows also maintains separate page table structures for its own kernel mode code and data.

This is important to remember: a process' address space is purely stored in memory, and never written back to the executable + DLLs from which the process was launched. The address space is discarded when the process exits. Modifications to mapped files that were opened for write access, however, will be flushed back their respective files.

---

> As far as I know the actual virtual memory addresses for the process are first stored within the program's .exe file. Meaning the linker will patch up all function references and variables with actual addresses such as 0x00007fb6.

No. That's only for references to program code; a process' address space also includes two or more heaps, a stack for every thread, and any additional address ranges the process's thread(s) happen to create as they run.

And these days even program code is (randomly) rearranged when loaded; this is known as ASLR and makes certain types of attacks harder.

> As far as I can conceptualize the OS gets an individual process's virtual address from the .exe

No. An executable only specifies the location of some initial data; namely, the program code, global variables and linked libraries. And even much of this information is overridden by ASLR in modern OSs.

Other memory (program heap, thread stacks, mapped files, etc.) are dynamically allocated by the program - their size, location, etc. can and will change during program execution.

As mentioned above, each process has its own independent virtual address space. A portion of it is mapped to kernel memory (which is marked not readable or modifiable from user mode) but the rest is private to the process. None of a process' address space is shared with other processes unless explicitly requested ("shared memory") or done completely transparently for performance (copy-on-write, mapped files).

**Figure 5-10** x86 virtual address space layouts (2 GB on the left, 3 GB on the right) from [Windows Internals, Part 1: System architecture, processes, threads, memory management, and more, 7th Edition](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/windows-internals-part-1-system-architecture-processes-9780735684188) is a good diagram showing the general process address space layout. Unfortunately I am not allowed to reproduce it here.

> so if another file's contents was being mapped into that process's virtual address space

This ends up as a special entry in a process' page table that tells the OS to load data from a mapped file. It's effectively a redirect; a "look elsewhere". Remember, the address space is *virtual* - it might refer to a file but that file will not be loaded until a thread tries to read/write it. And even then it will only be loaded one or a few pages at a time.

> then would those contents be saved back to the exe file

No. Executables are always loaded read-only. Once loaded, all relevant information is stored purely in memory and never "saved back" by the OS. Any changes to process memory are lost when the process exits, with the exception of writes to mapped files or shared memory.

> Or does the OS just keep track of the added contents behind the scenes some how?

Yes, which regions are mapped to which file are tracked in the process metadata.

Comment: re my edit: When the MMU tries to translate a virtual page number, then if the needed PTE is not already cached in the TLB, the MMU brings the needed PTE into the TLB automatically. The OS doesn't write that info to the TLB directly (and no reason I can think of to do so). The OS can, however, tell the CPU to _invalidate_ the TLB for a specific virtual page number; it does this whenever it changes the contents of a PTE. But loading the changed PTE into the TLB is only done by the MMU, on-demand, when and if the virtual page described by the PTE is translated.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Thanks for the edit. Admittedly the only practical experience I've had with OS memory management was on System/161 (MIPS), which would be somewhat different from x86. Notably, MIPS has a software-managed TLB while x86 is apparently hardware-managed (and, if I'm reading this correctly, does its page walks on the page table referred to by a control register?).

Comment: Yes. CR3 contains the physical address of the top-level page table (called the "page directory" on x86, "page directory pointer table" on x86 with PAE, "page-map level 4 table" on x64). Each process has a different tree of page tables and therefore a different value for CR3. A process context switch includes loading CR3 with the right value for the new process. This has a side effect of invalidating all entries in the TLB that don't have the "G" (global) flag set (referred to as "translation buffer shootdown"). Interesting about the MIPS, I did not know that!

Comment: btw, if you look at a system or a dump with windbg, in the !process output the "DirBase" field shows the CR3 contents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just so I solidify the concepts here, your saying that in actual RAM there is space reserved for the kernel to keep track of all processes virtual address space. So when a process say reserves a region of memory, the kernel then stores this information in physical RAM which can be looked up later if the process then needs to commit and use that reserved space?

Comment: @Boagz More or less, yes. The entire address space is always tracked (though, to save space, in a multi-level page table [larger blocks can be marked unused in a single entry at a higher level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467510) rather than individual entries for every page). [Reserving and committing are specific operations in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366916), but, yes, the page table is used to track which pages are free/reserved/committed/used. Not too sure if reserved/committed (but unused) is tracked per-page or per-block-of-pages.

Comment: For virtual address space, reserved, committed, and mapped ranges are tracked via Virtual Address Descriptors. Only committed and mapped pages that have actually been accessed necessarily have page table entries for their pages. There is no VAD for an unused range. Physical pages (RAM) are tracked via a variety of structures, primarily the "PFN array", which implements the system-wide page lists  (zeroed, free, standby, and modified) and keeps track of the usage of each physical page. Pages that are valid in processes are tracked via per-process lists called working set lists.